# How do I prevent one partial from hijacking the local variables from another in the same view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, erb, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a `Question#Show.html.erb` that has the following:

```
  <% @question.answers.each do |ans| %>
    <%= render partial: "questions/answer", locals: {ans: ans} %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="ibox">
          <div class="ibox-title">
              <h5>Your Refactor Suggestion</h5>
          </div>

          <div class="ibox-content">
            <%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {answer: @question.answers.build(user: current_user)} %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works fine.

However, once I flip it (i.e. put the `div.class=row` that is currently at the bottom above the iterator at the top), I get some crazy errors.

For instance, doing this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div class="ibox">
          <div class="ibox-title">
              <h5>Your Refactor Suggestion</h5>
          </div>

          <div class="ibox-content">
            <%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {answer: @question.answers.build(user: current_user)} %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <% @question.answers.each do |ans| %>
    <%= render partial: "questions/answer", locals: {ans: ans} %>
  <% end %>
```

Leads to this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /questions/42
No route matches {:action=>"vote_up", :controller=>"answers", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is my `questions/_answer.html.erb` partial (truncated for brevity):

```
        <%= link_to vote_up_answer_path(ans), method: :post do %>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"> </i>
        <% end %>
        <%= ans.cached_votes_total %>
        <%= link_to vote_down_answer_path(ans), method: :post do %>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"> </i>
        <% end %>
            <%= ans.body %>
                        <%= link_to ans.user.try(:email), user_path(ans.user) %>
```

Here is my `answers/_form.html.erb` partial (also truncated for brevity):

```
<%= simple_form_for(answer) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :question_id, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :user_id, as: :hidden %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input_field :body, as: :text, class: "form-control", rows: 8 %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input_field :language, collection: ["ruby", "python", "php"], as: :select, selected: "ruby", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div id="new-post-submission-button">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my `Questions#Show` controller:

```
  def show
    @question = Question.includes(:answers).find(params[:id])
  end
```

What could be causing that strange behavior?

Comment: Is this a specific issue with *Rails 5*? Did you tried this on *Rails 4.x*?

Comment: @Pavan I have not tested this on Rails 4.x. I am building my app using Rails 5 so that's where I am experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is in **building the associated answer** first (as in this part of code: `@question.answers.build(user: current_user)`). [`build`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-build-attributes) constructs a new association object (answer), sets the foreign keys link to the main object (question) and adds it to the associations collection (to all answers of the question). But it does not save it yet, thus it has indeed no ID yet.

So when you render your partial next for all members of the question's answers association, this includes the newly created answer from above as well. You should probably skip the newly created answer when rendering the partials. **Update:** To do so, you can do something like the following (there are many ways to achieve the same, this is just an example):

```
@question.answers.select { |ans| ans.persisted? }.each do |ans|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Interesting. How do I skip the newly created answer if it has no ID? I can't do `Answer.last` or anything like that because the record isn't saved...right? Do you have an example in code for how I might do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can simply skip the newly created record when traversing the answers collection. See the answer update for an example.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Thanks!